# UWP IconElement Property Value Editor

Tags: c#, custom-controls, uwp, property-editor

In my class I have an IconElement property defined. When I want to select its value in design time in the property editor, the editor is different than property editor used for system controls like AppBarButton. AppBarButton.Icon property editor allows to switch between different types of glyphs (SymbolIcon, FontIcon, PathIcon, ...).

Is there an attribute I can decorate my property with to use this editor?

[image: Property Value Editor]

Answer (score 1):

After performing some research on this issue, it appears this isn't possible on a custom control since the required *designer attributes* aren't available in UWP, so this will not work.

Our core control like the `AppBarButton` has this since this is done internally and doesn't depend on the designer attributes like it's done on WPF.

At this time, this behavior is by design.

Please submit your requirement/feedback using **windows feedback app**, this is a good way to let MS know what users/developers need.